# CWE-ID 100 Fix for MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, veracode

Our application is being dinged several hundred times CWE-ID 100 "flaws" related to *Technology-Specific Input Validation Problems* according to Veracode.

According to their docs, the remediation is to check the `ModelState.IsValid` property on a model before using it. We do this on every controller action yet we are still dinged. An example controller action follows.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DeliverySummary (ReportsViewModel Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /* Other processing occurs here */ 

        //finally return View
        return View(Model);
    }
    else 
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

We have the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` on our model properties.

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: Post your model properties & which properties dinged CWE problem. I searched similar problem on SO and just found single entry here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289347/veracode-throws-technology-specific-input-validation-problems-cwe-id-100-for.

Comment: Our view models are huge..Do you want to see the entire thing? They did not say which properties dinged the scan results. That's the entire problem here.. I don't know what they're dinging us for :/

Answer (score 5):

I've been dealing with this myself. The basic culprit is you don't have [Bind] set on your argument, specifying the properties that are allowed.

My old sign-in controller action was like this

`public ActionResult SignIn(SignInViewModel viewModel)`

And to correct it, I need it to read like this

`public ActionResult SignIn([Bind(Include = "Email,Password,UtcOffset")]SignInViewModel viewModel)`

What this says to MVC is only the properties `Email`, `Password` and `UtcOffset` will be read from `SignInViewModel`, so if a hacker also set `LastLogonTime` it would be ignored.

As an aside, due to the security checks from Veracode, I'm thinking this kind of model-binding is now incredibly awkward, considering devs now have to keep strings in sync with prop names at the target. What a hassle.

Comment: I came across the `Bind` possible solution as well and implemented that on a few controller actions to test, but the "flaws" were still present in the scan results. We've opened a tech support ticket with veracode after one of their security techs found no problems with our code on a consultation call. He was baffled as to why we were being dinged. I'll post back what I hear once they figure this out

Comment: I also completely agree that having to add `Bind` to each and every controller action is incredibly clumsy. Almost all of the research I've done into this flaw in particular seems to revolve around Entity framework and direct db changes from your model that is passed into a controller. We don't use EF at all and have completely abstracted our DAL following a repository pattern with stored procedures. I wish Veracode's platform was smart enough to realize when EF is being used or not, and report EF "flaws" accordingly

Comment: @mituw16 did you hear back from veracode regarding your query? We are also facing same issue in our application.

Comment: @hgarg I did actually, yes. They needed to make changes in their scanning engine. They had a problem in their scanning engine related to our use of an async controller action that was causing an issue.I finally noticed their scanners didn't have problems with non async controller actions. After we figured that out, they fixed a problem with their scanner engine and all was well. The entire process was honestly a huge run around that took almost 2 months to resolve before they *finally* admitted there was a bug in their engine.